# Authorization middleware never execute after taking the token from cookies. why is it? Code is below

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cookies, authorization

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const { User } = require('../model/user');

const authenticate = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {

        const token = req.cookies.jwtoken
        console.log(`i am from authorization `)//This line never execute
         if (!token) return res.status(403).json({ message: "Access denied" })
        //all user info from database will be saved of this verified token
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
        const rootUser = await User.findOne({ _id: decoded._id, 'tokens.token': token })
        if (!rootUser) return res.status(400).send("User Not Found")
        req.token = token;
        req.rootUser = rootUser;
        req.userId = rootUser._id
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(401).send("unathorized!No token Provided")
        next()
    }
}
module.exports = authenticate;
```

Comment: Maybe execution goes to `catch` after do `req.cookies.jwtoken`?

Comment: yes, it is always going to the catch block after getting the cookie .I can not identify the problem here :(

Comment: And what is the `err` into `catch`?

Comment: Basically, I am trying to authenticate a page. without login, the page can not be shown. after login, I also can not see the page content. the error is unauthorized! No token Provided which I commanded catch block to send in response.it never executes the try block after getting the token that's why in the backend it can not verify the logged-in user. But why it is not executing other lines in try block